# Is there a way to disable the option to save a certain file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to open vscode with certain files opened as readonly, if such option exists, but if  I'll be more specific about what I want, I don't really want to make the file purely readonly because I might want to go over it and maybe add some comments for myself in the process, so I want to be able to do that, hence the file shouldn't really be purely readonly, but what I want is to cancel the option to save the file, so any changes I might have made will not impact the file.

anyone knows how to do that?
if not, I will also be satisfied in knowing how to open a file as purely readonly.

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use File & Folder Watcher extension which is available in visual studio marketplace. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=appulate.filewatcher 
It will help you to track File content and Folder content changes before save .